# SqlFunctions.StringConvert returning wrong results

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using SQLServer2008 R2 and need to search on decimal data field
I have rows like

```
ID | Amount 
1     68.88 
2     65.55
```

Where Amount is of type decimal(18, 2)

Now i am using EntityFramework6.0 and making query like

```
whereClause = t => (#some_condition1) &&
                   (#some_condition2) &&
                   SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal)t.Amount).Contains(searchfields)
```

Where searchfields is a string datatype and will contain "68" expectation is it should get row with ID 1(substring search)

Now interesting this is if i search 68.88 it is searching but not 68.

**EDIT**

The culprit was **SqlFunctions.StringConvert** for sql server it is rounding while conversion so

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert(68.88) will get converted to 69
```

Now question is how to avoid this rounding.

**UPDATE**
Use Floor function to get the number without caring about decimals

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert(decimal.Floor(68.88)) will get converted to 68
```

Answer (score 1):

try the  `SqlFunctions.StringConvert()` from 
`system.data.entity.sqlserver` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
whereClause = t => (#some_condition1) &&
                   (#some_condition2) &&
                   SqlFunctions.StringConvert((int)t.Amount).Contains(Convert.ToInt32(searchfields))
```

Comment: Contains function is not overloaded to take integer or decimal.

Comment: means beside searchfields = "68.88,65.55", use searchfields = "68,65"

Comment: searchfields="68" is not working and this is what is required, user will search for some number and i need to show if it matches even in substring.

Comment: what do you mean by not working ? can you be specific with output you are getting?

Comment: Ahh..got it you will be surprised that issue was with SqlFunctions.StringConvert() which is doing rounding
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527(v=sql.105).aspx